# about Initialized Captures of the C++14 lambdas

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Why the value x is updated to 6, and y is initialized to 7?

Could anybody give me some clues?

```
int x = 4;
auto y = [&r = x, x = x+1]()->int {
            r += 2;
            return x+2;
         }();  // Updates ::x to 6, and initializes y to 7.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the capture group:

```
[&r = x, x = x+1]
```

`r` is a *reference* to `x`, so any changes to `r` are reflected in `x`. On the other hand, the left hand side `x` in the capture group, is a *copy* of `x+1`, where the right hand side `x` comes from outside the lambda.

Since the confusion is coming about from the fact that lambda capture syntax, is different than regular assignment syntax, changing the name of this copy will make it clearer what's happening:

```
int x = 5;
auto y = [&r = x, x_copy = x+1]() ->int {  // x_copy is 5
            r += 2;     // changes x
            return x_copy + 2;    // returns 7
         }();
```

This is equivalent to your example, so you can see that the only change to `x` is via `r`, so it becomes `6`. The local `x_copy` is initialized to `5`, and then the lambda returns `x_copy + 2`, which is `7`.

Comment: Why [x=x+1] does not change the value of the outer x?

Comment: @孙世龙 Why should it? Here `=` is not the assignment operator, but a part of the capturing syntax. Its lhs is always the name of the capture to be created, even if it's same as the name of some variable.

Comment: As I said, the lhs `x` is a *copy*, it does *not* modify the outer `x`.

Comment: @cigien I could draw the conclusion that the address of x in [x=x+1] is not the same with the outer one?Am i right？

Comment: @ HolyBlackCat  **Nice to see you again!** I wonder that the lhs one in capturing syntax wheather has a memory address or not.I mean if i could get the address of the rls one in {}.Linke this: [&r = x, x = x+1](){&x;}

Comment: Yes, that's perfectly fine.